# Displaying percentage inside pie item for highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to display the percentage for each pie item inside the actual pie item for highcharts?  Example of what I mean is something like this:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You may want to look @ [`dataLabels.formatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.formatter). `this.percentage` option is available for pie

Also [`dataLabels.distance`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.distance) can be set to a negative value for dataLabels inside the pie.

[Pie with percentage values inside @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/uhydP/)

Answer (score 8):

Its suprisingly easy. In your tooltip or dataLabels section change your format.

```
FROM:
  format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y:.1f} Rs.',
TO:
  format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. It works for me:

```
  'labelFormatter':function () { 
       var total = 0, percentage; 
       $.each(this.series.data, function() { 
          total+=this.y; 
       }); 

       percentage=((this.y/total)*100).toFixed(1); 
       return this.name+' '+percentage+'%'; 
    }
```