# Semi-circle donut pie chart with labels (data names) and %-ages on the pie ... and data numbers on mousehover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, highcharts

The goal is to create a pie chart, where

- the percentages (calculated or manually specified) are shown inside the pie.
- data is shown upon mousehover.

*Clarification: e.g. imagine a set consisting of 2 data labels. One is called **apples** (containing "15" apples), and the other one is called **pears** (containing "15" pears), then the percentages, always visible, shown inside the pie would be "50%" and "50%", whereas the data shown on mousehover would be "15" and "15".*

Such has been already done in a previous post: [Displaying percentage inside pie item for highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529934/displaying-percentage-inside-pie-item-for-highcharts) with [JSFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/uhydP/).

---

However, would it be possible to

- use a semi-circle donut pie chart, instead of a circle pie chart. (what is a semi-circle donut pie chart? -> [JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-semi-circle/))?
- have text labels (data names) on the chart inside the pie chart, such as in Fiddle 2.

*Clarification: e.g. having the data labels "**apples**" and "**pears**" on the pie by default, such as "*Firefox*" and "*Chrome*" in Fiddle 2.*

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I find it hard to combine these Fiddles, since I am far underexperienced with JS.

E.g. *Fiddle 1* works/starts with `$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({`,

whereas *Fiddle 2* starts with `$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({`.

The [Highcharts API Reference manual](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) is learning me slowly, as a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm not sure which you prefer here is a fiddle you can look at that leverage the `highcharts formatter` attribute:

```
formatter: function() {
       return Math.round(this.percentage*100)/100 + ' %';
}
```

I believe what you want is something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/potk4jpd/5/).

Comment: Thanks, a very good and fast answer. Your first combination would be great! --- However, would you think it is possible to have the texts (data labels) (i.c. *Firefox*, *Chrome*, ...) inside the pie, always visible, such as in Fiddle 2 (to show **apples** and **pears** on the pie by default)?

Comment: @VincentVerheyen do you mean like this --> http://jsfiddle.net/potk4jpd/4/? I think you are misunderstanding what a pie chart is. The percentages are calculated by the number of a specific type say `apples` divided by the total number of items. So if you had 15 apples and 15 pears each would be split 50% because the total number is 30. If you had 10 apples, 10 pears, and 10 oranges each would be 33.3%.

Comment: I apologize for my misunderstanding. I first thought your answer didn't calculate the percentages, and just showed the original mousehover data again, but with a %-mark after them). Later, I noticed I was mistaken. --- You had already achieved this aspect of the question, great! --- The only remaining part is getting the labels (**apples** and **pears**) on the pie.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen see the edit that I just made to my answer, namely the fiddle I added at the end.

Comment: You nailed it! Many thanks. --- And you are handing out pies? You are the one who should be getting presents. :)

Comment: If you would still have some more motivation, I just asked a similar question with the same features as your solution, but using a **single horizontal stacked bar** instead of a *pie chart*. The question can be found here: [Highcharts single horizontal stacked bar chart with data names (labels) and %-ages always shown and data numbers and series name shown on mousehover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124459/highcharts-single-horizontal-stacked-bar-chart-with-data-names-labels-and-ag).